# Conventional name for directory containing HTML snippets to be used in templates

Tags: php, html, playframework

Is there a naming convention for the folder that contains the templated parts of a site's HTML (e.g. `<head>` and `<footer>` sections that are repeated across the site)? I've worked in many different offices with different conventions for this (/inc for php, /Controls for .net, etc.), but I'm starting a new project using Play! Framework and I wondered what name (and location, for that matter – within the Views directory?) would be best for ease of recognition by potential future co-developers. Whether it's Play!-specific or just a general rule of thumb, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no conventional naming for this.

Partial view, snippets, controls, includes, sections are all suitable names (and there are probably many others).

The best name is one that your team agrees on.

Comment: I like the idea of partials. Thanks guys!